# Xamarin Switch 'Tint Colour' Android renderer makes switches dissapear

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am implementing a custom renderer for Xamarin Forms. All I want to do is change the On colour of the switch...

I have a custom class for my switch & and have added a bindable 'TintColour' property.

```
public class ExtendedSwitch : Switch
{
    //Solution from: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/ExtendedSwitch.cs

    /// <summary>
    /// Bindable tint colour property (sets colour of switch).
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty TintColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(TintColor),
        typeof(Color),
        typeof(ExtendedSwitch),
        defaultValue: Color.FromHex(Constants.kProtirusBlueHexString)
    );

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the color of the tint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The color of the tint.</value>
    public Color TintColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(TintColorProperty); }

        set { SetValue(TintColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I have set my switches in XAML here:

```
<controls:ExtendedSwitch TintColor="Black" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" IsToggled="true"/>
<controls:ExtendedSwitch TintColor="Green" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" IsToggled="true"/>
<controls:ExtendedSwitch TintColor="Gray" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" IsToggled="true"/>
<controls:ExtendedSwitch TintColor="Blue" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" IsToggled="true"/>
<controls:ExtendedSwitch TintColor="#ff9200" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" IsToggled="true"/>
<controls:ExtendedSwitch TintColor="Gray" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" IsToggled="true"/>
<controls:ExtendedSwitch TintColor="Red" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" IsToggled="true"/>
```

And i have implemented a renderer on iOS:

```
public class ExtendedSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the current state of Extended Switch.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The element.</value>
    public new ExtendedSwitch Element
    {
        get { return (ExtendedSwitch)base.Element; }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Apply Tint Colour to Switch.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">E.</param>
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.OnTintColor = Element.TintColor.ToUIColor();
        }
    }
}
```

And look how beautiful it looks...

[image: iOS behaves nicely & gives the intended result.]

Now, we come to implementing an android renderer & it just refuses to work.

Firstly I will say that this HAS to be done in code, I CANT use a style / theme to achieve this as each switch must be a different colour.

First lets have a look at my android code:
**EDIT***I have added the full renderer class, instead of just the code affecting the switch*

```
public class ExtendedSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
    public ExtendedSwitchRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the current state of Extended Switch.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The element.</value>
    public new ExtendedSwitch Element
    {
        get { return (ExtendedSwitch)base.Element; }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            this.SetTintColor(Element.TintColor);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the color of the tint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="color">The color.</param>
    private void SetTintColor(Xamarin.Forms.Color color)
    {
        //Colours currently hard coded but I will pass `Element.TintColour` to them
        Android.Graphics.Color colorOn = Android.Graphics.Color.Green;
        Android.Graphics.Color colorOff = Android.Graphics.Color.Gray;
        Android.Graphics.Color colorDisabled = Android.Graphics.Color.Green;

        StateListDrawable drawable = new StateListDrawable();
        drawable.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked }, new ColorDrawable(colorOn));
        drawable.AddState(new int[] { -Android.Resource.Attribute.StateEnabled }, new ColorDrawable(colorDisabled));
        drawable.AddState(new int[] { }, new ColorDrawable(colorOff));

        this.Control.ThumbDrawable = drawable;
    }
}
```

When I load the page with the switches on, they are completely missing. No colours have been set & there are no switches.

I have also tried setting `Control.ThumbStateList` with a `ColorStateList` however the exact same thing happens, the switches vanish.

How can I get this to work? I have checked the code for [XLabs Forms' implementation of this renderer](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.Droid/Controls/ExtendedSwitch/ExtendedSwitchRenderer.cs) and it is the same as mine, and doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea on how I can set it so that my Switches have a different colour when selected on Android.

Side note, I do not want to use an Effect. [I followed the steps in this guide for achieving the same thing with an Effect.](https://blog.wislon.io/posts/2017/05/15/xamforms-change-switch-colour) But this didn't work even on iOS so I was a step behind where I currently am...

Any & all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hey, show us the full code of your android renderer.

Comment: @MichałŻołnieruk I have updated the post to show all of the android code. All methods do get called, I have tested with breakpoints!

Comment: @MichałŻołnieruk Did you ever have a look at this?